# Snippet that depend on the selection

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I'm looking for a tool that could help me to do the following operation:

Given that code:

```
const before = (arg1: string, arg2: string) => null;
```

I would like to have the following result:

```
const after = ({ arg1, arg2 }: { arg1: string; arg2: string }) => null;
```

Is it possible to do that with a snippet ? (for exemple, i select my args and it directly transform them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the following Typescript snippet

```json
  "Convert Arguments": {
    "prefix": "conarg",
    "body": [
      "{ ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(\\w+):[^,]*(,\\s*)?/$1$2/g} }: { ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/,/;/g}}"
    ],
    "description": "Convert Arguments"
  }
```

- select the arguments between `()`
- type `conarg` and select the snippet

Answer (score 0):

As I generally need to execute a considerably big list of changes, I tend to use Tasks (Ctrl+Shift+P/Run Task/[task name])
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

```js
        {
            "label": "vueconv",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "tsx scripts/vueconv ${file}",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": true,
                "panel": "shared",
                "showReuseMessage": false,
                "clear": true
            }
        },
```

My scripts read the file, make fixes (mostly with `string.replace(/regex/g, callback)`), and overwrite the file
I only use `${file}`, but if you can also add line number or selection as script arguments
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

[self-made somple replacer library](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKzHAZlCI4HIUGcC0CApjGAIYDGA1lgNwCwAUE0QB6SxwUA2ZuucAGLBWRKHADeTAJBQiZACYQAdtwCeccjAAWALji4YUYMoDmDRrPlLVGgO7GYZAEbci%205xAhuyyizLlFFXVUYDd9Q2MzC2kiBWAYOOFwgyMTcyYZChVIgFcKGGgACgUyJ30JOETDZKIABTLtAH4ItLM4AF84AF5JDoBKSRlpHWBcADoHBJc3HrgAQnmwdAoifnGyKFMANwBtACYAXWHRia1tOdPJxxmiOCbNFbWJzZ2Dw7h9Uqdx6phaho6e4PLB0YbAFBwIrzK7nQY6dB2ODKIhIgCiUHQUCKWBAY1w6VCs0KcCguWU8yw-WG2WUuG8RHG3AgpiKlXO%20lhjQANHApolOdoxtdpq4iLy2GMYLh9EhxpLDLgilydIMBplLCMhRMUGE7r0inLAgpldrxnDgdgqeM5GBeKsAILcbg4gA6UFdyiwvKwnqpMS1wriCSSesuZt1bhiHQ10hAZCoRGErCKaAwrSipjgAB84AAlIimNHsXmFfRFcaVsgZ9K7Q6DboAPlSmf6grGQ01tMMmjKiSgykuajARAgkLTmG6vSwkXSWGG0geE5tRDtlCITpdAHoigA-fpNIq7CQdIr9etb0y8oq4XlkXnOGtmBvNsj3ODOT7YV2urBwADUH7Upq0jSCua6Os6RQ7k0AA88z7p6rq4AAVJePo-rg-5UguYG2vaG5QVgu5%20hhXrAaB0j6KCNI5PAcimGwQ4jmOqDoJO06zmYf4PCiSIFkW7BFFo-bKIM%20gTrRdIMkyLJFAxbAUdI3bwJOVRmsGiQKLU4zxjAFDaPJhaKeCkLQiAgyVN2MnMqyWDKBA8AoBA5IKP6pIkLkA7qWMtCdFJ9JuLJdn4KFYVhThXY5DZckgLsAAMhy-MYIBnkp1lBbZOL4NsOV5blkWgRljJZXFiXgQRRmMaw16VhsT6mHWL5VBAFZVv0yWgGl6XRZlclYOFg2FdIbjwM4RDOXI4ZBvEWm1CcGmzaGsy9FcmnLYy%20HrlVbC1VWDVNT0zaFG1Gz9EpEJQmtS3aWG8xTh%20E3QEQlkLlc8aJsmqbsaWEBKTGmpyDAXmDqc0axrqyhjIZr2apdpozSGt0rQ9VyRi9naUcVwU4gAchAXDaL4jETMNXRENwuB3FIIHY1lWC1ITxNxOMw3SPDMJmvytyw5Rym9SV-UAOqOISuBUMAYAjgorNKaBQMgwG0gA5Rcr8kQCNnDyPkTOtyObauBGbm6XoYR65Fy3T-WMxA2xiMYChEMossLluW5cALONYHm5JQ%200azcCYMB1Wzbse9JQUwKAGtYAHQeh%207RgaDTlFh7EogUAAymoygUEUAAGaibIOcfKPAoUUJQ2h3KFuqsHAAAkEgqtoHT57ylSGPEEDUSY1eOFg6ogWHXSV-pFwnq77vY1HIBEGiygmrHuCB2XZMBTFdkACIqIyhUAwDTBAA)

Comment: your `typescriptlang.org` link results in an almost empty script